# PHP preg_replace not working as intended in this code

Tags: php, regex

My intention is to remove any attribute which does not have value.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php
$srcTxt = "
|title=
|Row18={{Timeline row
  |from=
  |to=2000
  |1-text= TYRR consolidation
  |1-at= 1904
  |2-text= TYRR and TFC takeover
  |2-at= 1927
  |3-text= private bus services acquisition
  |3-at= 1954
|Row18={{Scale row|
  |from=1840
  |to=2000
  |increment=40
  }}
}} ";

$srcTxt = preg_replace("/^ *.*= *$/m", "", $srcTxt);

echo ($srcTxt);

?>
```

The expected output is to remove `|title=` and `|from=` which do not have any values assigned to them.

This works perfectly [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) But not so when I run it locally in my system. What might be the issue?

Comment: Does it replace nothing or only the first occurence (`|title=`) when you run it on your system?

Comment: @BastiM Nothing changes in the output. Not even the first `|title`...

Comment: Just tried it and it works correctly (PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u2). What version do you run?

Comment: @JayarathinaMadharasan: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. It [works fine](http://3v4l.org/hHiI8). Can you show the output you're getting now and the expected output?

Comment: @MikeS. My version is 5.4.19 Built: Aug 21 2013 01:07:08

Comment: @AmalMurali here you go: http://i.imgur.com/znfMUli.jpg (First and third line removed in exp., op; Also I did save the code.. i modified it to take screenshot)

Comment: What's your PCRE Library Version? (run phpinfo() to check)

Comment: The code sample works here, but there may be an issue with 'other whitespace' in the actual original string (so not the one provided here). You could replace those spaces with `\s` to capture other whitespace characters well.

Comment: To @kontrollfreak: `PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support: enabled` and `PCRE Library Version: 8.32 2012-11-30`

Comment: To @Wrikken: do you want me to do something like revo's answer below? That works.

Comment: @JayarathinaMadharasan: yes, indeed like that (wasn't loaded when I put in the comment). Essentially:`\s` also captures tabs and the like, and I believe that to have been the issue.

Comment: If the "|" in your posting is actually a _tab_, you should be using `\s` to capture spaces, tabs, etc. Be careful to use "non-greedy" matches for "." or they could eat everything up to the end of the sub-line ($). The "m" modifier should apply the ^ and $ line markers to each sub-line. I think revo's posting covers most of this.

Comment: @PhilPerry For my scenario a tab char should not be present in the string. And I am pretty sure tab is not present in the string. http://i.imgur.com/143Zv9i.jpg But \s is a good idea. Still curious of why this happens

Comment: @Wrikken There is no tab char in the string: http://i.imgur.com/143Zv9i.jpg

Comment: There _are_ however `\r`'s, which aren't spaces either, and also fall in the `\s` category AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$srcTxt = "
|title=
|Row18={{Timeline row
  |from=
  |to=2000
  |1-text= TYRR consolidation
  |1-at= 1904
  |2-text= TYRR and TFC takeover
  |2-at= 1927
  |3-text= private bus services acquisition
  |3-at= 1954
|Row18={{Scale row|
  |from=1840
  |to=2000
  |increment=40
  }}
}} ";

$srcTxt = trim(preg_replace("/(.+?)=\s*\n/", '', $srcTxt));
echo $srcTxt ;
```

**Output**:

```
|Row18={{Timeline row
  |to=2000
  |1-text= TYRR consolidation
  |1-at= 1904
  |2-text= TYRR and TFC takeover
  |2-at= 1927
  |3-text= private bus services acquisition
  |3-at= 1954
|Row18={{Scale row|
  |from=1840
  |to=2000
  |increment=40
  }}
}}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot... That code works... :) But I am still curious why my code did not work.

Comment: @JayarathinaMadharasan Your snippet doesn't work on my localhost either, and I found that this issue is due to white spaces which I managed in the regex correctly. I didn't go deep to find the answer but.